# Word counter (Introduction to Programming 2(python))

Tags: python

I tried looking for an answer to this problem but it didn't work. (btw I am 15 and basically just started python)
This is my program:

```
all = []

count = {}

line = input("Enter line: ")

while line:

    word = line.split()

    line = input("Enter line: ")

for w in word:

    if w in count:

        count[w] += 1

    else:

        count[w] = 1

for word in sorted(count):

    print(word, count[word])
```

This is the answer I'm getting:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 1
```

When I should be getting:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 2
witch 1
```

Please, can someone help?

Comment: You should store `word` somewhere. In the while loop, each time it runs you are overwritting the value

Comment: You asked adding all the necessary info, in a clear and concise way. Thumbs (vote) up! :)

Answer (score 3):

`for w in word:` loop is executed outside `while line:` loop. It means that first you produce single `word` list for each `line` and then you skip each such list end executes `for w in word:` only for last `word` list.

To fix it change indentation of whoole `for w in word:` loop (this line and 4 lines below). Move it 4 spaces to the right.

```
all = []
count = {}
line = input("Enter line: ")
while line:
    print("line is :" + line )
    word = line.split()
    line = input("Enter line: ")
    for w in word:
        if w in count:
            count[w] += 1
        else:
            count[w] = 1
for word in sorted(count):
    print(word, count[word])
```

It's because [indentation in python is used to determine grouping of statements](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

Comment: I tried putting it 4 spaces to the right an error showed up:
  File "program.py", line 8
    if w in count:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @calamri Indent everything inside the for loop as well

Comment: Still says the same thing

Comment: @calamri: Just fix indentation of your code. Make sure number of spaces in each line is consistent. Set auto indentation in your editor and make sure all tabs are automatically replaced by 4 spaces.

Comment: @calamri Check you are always using spaces when indenting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way using `Counter` from `collections` module, it will give a dict with list elements as key at its frequency as values, it may help you to reduce the code length and use of for loop, [You can get more idea about Counter from here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
:

```
from collections import Counter

all = []
line = input("Enter line: ")
while line:
    all.extend(line.split())
    line = input("Enter line : ")

for i,j in Counter(all).items():
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: I tried it, this is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 7, in <module>
    for i,j in Counter(all).items():
NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

Comment: Changing all the algorithm, using an additional library, all without explaining.

Comment: @calamri which python version are you using and are you sure imported Counter from collections ?

Comment: I am using grok

Comment: @calamri have you pasted this line also `from collections import Counter` ?

Comment: Because Collections is a library and Counter is a module , if you want to use it you have to  import library and call the Counter module.

Comment: I tried it and it worked but it saying:
Enter line: which witch
Enter line : is which
Enter line : 
which 2
witch 1
is 1
when it was meant to output:

Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 2
witch 1
​

Comment: so basically making the is first for some reason

Comment: on what base you have to arrange the order of words ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174798/discussion-between-calamri-and-vikas-damodar).

Comment: what do u mean base?